# Remove one (or more) aes from legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is sure a simple question, but I have not find a quick and easy solution.
I just want to remove one aes from the legend, for example in the figure, I don't want that the "2 dot" appear:

[image]

BTW, that's the code of the plot:

```
ggplot(subset(df, df$ID %in% c( "B4F", "B3F", "B33F", "B2F", "B0F")), 
       aes(Date, SO4, color=ID))+
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F, size=1)+
  geom_point(data=subset(df_1, df_1$ID %in% c( "B4F", "B3F", "B33F", "B2F", "B0F")),
             aes(Date, SO4, color=ID, size=2, legend=FALSE))+
  scale_x_date(labels= date_format("%Y"), breaks=date_breaks("year"))+
  xlab(NULL)
```

Comment: `geom_point( .... , blah , blah , show_guide = FALSE )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `size=2` from the `aes`. Hence, change

```
geom_point(data=subset(df_1, df_1$ID %in% c( "B4F", "B3F", "B33F", "B2F", "B0F")),
             aes(Date, SO4, color=ID, size=2, legend=FALSE))
```

to

```
geom_point(data=subset(df_1, df_1$ID %in% c( "B4F", "B3F", "B33F", "B2F", "B0F")),
                 aes(Date, SO4, color=ID, legend=FALSE), size=2)
```

In the latter code, `size=2` is still inside `geom_point`, but outside `aes`.